# Header of ucbletter

Tags: header-footer

I want to copy only header that is available in [`ucbletter`](https://chess.eecs.berkeley.edu/ptexternal/wiki/uploads/Main/ucbletter.zip), downloadable from [here](https://chess.eecs.berkeley.edu/ptexternal/wiki/Main/LaTeX), and use it in my own cover letter. This `ucbletter` header is shown in below for better clarification.

[image]
Could someone help me which part of `ucletter.sty` I need to copy in my own document so that it appears only in the first page?

Here is the LaTeX code in which I want to replace the header with `ucbletter` header:

```
% Cover letter using letter.sty
\documentclass{letter} % Uses 10pt
%Use \documentstyle[newcent]{letter} for New Century Schoolbook postscript font


% the following commands control the margins:
\topmargin=-1in    % Make letterhead start about 1 inch from top of page 
\textheight=8in  % text height can be bigger for a longer letter
\oddsidemargin=0pt % leftmargin is 1 inch
\textwidth=6.5in   % textwidth of 6.5in leaves 1 inch for right margin

%\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\signature{FirstName LastName}           % name for signature 
\longindentation=0pt                       % needed to get closing flush left
\let\raggedleft\raggedright                % needed to get date flush left


\begin{letter} {
Ms. XXX \\
XXX \\
XYZ Corporation \\
Rt. 56 \\
Anytown, XXX 05867
}


\begin{flushleft}
    {\large\bf FirstName LastName}
\end{flushleft}
\medskip\hrule height 1pt
\begin{flushright}
    \hfill 12345 My Address, MyCity, State 12345 \\
    \hfill (123) 456-7890 
\end{flushright} 
\vfill % forces letterhead to top of page

\opening{To whom it may concern,}
```

Comment: Could you confirm that you have permission to use this? I ask because some people mistakenly believe that if it is online, it must be all right to use it, but that's obviously not the case.

Comment: I am currently affiliated with the University of California.

Comment: In fact, Berkely has a LaTeX class for letters and similar documents which produces the letter head automatically. So I would suggest that you use that class. I don't have a current version but if you ask a LaTeX-using colleague, they can tell you where to get it. That class automatically puts the customised bits of your information in the standardised places so it will be better than just sticking the header on top of an ordinary letter. Also, the logo is available in metafont format which works well. (By now, I expect they may have moved to vector.)

Comment: @cfr where is this latex class that berkeley supposedly has?  i am a UCB student and i have no idea what you're talking about.

Comment: @dbliss I got a copy from a colleague. I don't know whether it is available to students, though. Normally, they would not be expected to use it. (Possibly some exceptional cases for e.g. graduate students asked to write references, but that is relatively unusual.)

Comment: @cfr we seem to be living in different worlds. i am a graduate student who has written many references and right now need to send a formal letter to a federal agency on ucb letterheard. i thought you were talking about something official that berkeley has, not some informal file a few professors have passed around. i did find such an informal file, though. maybe it is what you have.

Comment: @dbliss Maybe it is department specific. When I asked for letterhead, this is what I was given. But my department was slightly rogue when it cam to IT.

Comment: @dbliss We used to encourage students to find faculty for references, if possible. However, maybe UCB takes a different attitude. Or maybe it is more common in some disciplines. From a UK perspective, it seems kind of weird. But I know it happens in the US: sometimes students just don't have sufficient contact with faculty to ask one for a reference. (Certainly I wrote some in this kind of case.)